# How to use the Custom dimensions and Metrics of Google Analytics in Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api, google-tag-manager, looker-studio

I've been working with Google analytics since now, and as a part of the new update, I need to implement everything using Google Tag Manager. How do I use my custom dimensions and metrics of Ga in GTM? How's Data layer connected with GA's dimensions and Metrics? I'm very new to this tools, so please pardon me for any mistakes in the question and feel free to edit it. I'm confused with the other sources in Google and other documentations regarding these topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Universal Analytics tag, click the "enable overriding settings in this tag" checkbox, go to more settings, custom dimensions, click the "add custom dimension" button, enter in the left field the numeric index as obtained via the GA property settings and in the right field your value/variable. Similar for metrics.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your valuable info. My Value of the dimension is an organization name, which I need to take dynamically using javascript for each page view. How do I Implement that logic here?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing your site - ideally you would have a "dataLayer" implementation that contains the value, alternatively you can use global JS variables, DOM scraping, meta elements, data attributes.... Impossible to know what would work for you without knowing more details.

Comment: As per you said I created dimension and metrics in GTM. Now I need to send data from Web using Data layer. My task is to send the name/value at every time the page loads. So I think I can push the name value to the data layer every time the page loads. Is this correct?

Comment: That would be the preferred solution (if you do DOM scraping or similar you have to wait until the DOM is actually available, passing the value to the dataLayer makes sure you can send your page view immediately).

Comment: One more thing. I went through all the triggers in the GTM, I need to fire a tag when the user presses the search button in our web, how do I implement this?